# Casting a class using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I have the following classes.

```
abstract class A{}

class B extends A{}

class C extends A{}
```

I need to create an object like this

```
A a = new B();
```

I get the class name of the subclass at runtime. So, I need to use reflection to create an object.

I have done this.

```
Class<?> klass = Class.forName(className);
```

Now I am not able to cast this class to the subclass.

I want to achieve

```
A a = klass.newInstance(); // returns Object
```

I want the object to be casted into the subclass (either `B` or `C`, decided on runtime)

How do I do this?

Comment: What's wrong with `A a = (A)klass.newInstance();` ?

Comment: @AleksG I need to access the functions in the subclass.

Comment: What's wrong with `switch (name) { case "B": return new B(); case "C": return new C(); default: throw new SomeException(); }`? / What's wrong with `Class.newInstance`? Plenty. If you're going through `Constructor.newInstance`, better to use `asSubclass` up front.

Comment: Since you are using reflection anyway, you don't really have to cast them to use the functions in the subclass...

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I am doing it in the same method as you mentioned. but I just feel its not a cleaner way of doing it.

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? I got a feeling the casting is not the real problem.

Comment: See my answer for how to invoke methods on this object.

Comment: @rgksugan There's nothing clean about reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Generics to declare

```
Class<? extends A> klass;
```

then you'll be allowed to write

```
A a = klass.newInstance();
```

However, since `Class.forName` has no type information on your class, and has no type inference declared, you'll be getting "unchecked cast" warnings. This approach is no more typesafe than just downcasting the result of the second line to `A`.

Comment: Incompatible types. found: Class<capture<?>>

Comment: Yes. You need an explicit cast on the right-hand side. Anyway, it doesn't give you much mileage: you can't make an inherently type-unsafe piece of code type-safe.

Comment: `A a = Class.forName( … ).asSubclass(A.class).newInstance();` does even work without unchecked type casts and is type safe.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the object to be casted into the subclass (either B or C, decided on runtime)

That makes no sense. Casting is something which is primarily a compile-time operation, to end up with an expression of the appropriate type. It's then verified at execution time.

If you're really trying to achieve a variable of type `A`, then you only need to cast to `A`:

```
A a = (A) klass.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `klass` object of type `Class<T>` you can call [`Class.cast()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) method to cast to type `T` using

```
klass.cast(object)
```

For example, you have `a` of type `B`, you cast `a` to type `B` loaded at runtime.

```
Class<?> klass = Class.forName("B");
klass.cast(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on the comments, you can create your instance of the class with either

```
Class klass = Class.forName(className);
A a = (A)klass.newInstance();
```

or

```
Class<? extends A> klass = Class.forName(className);
A a = klass.newInstance();
```

Then you can invoke a method on it with:

```
klass.getMethod(methodName, null).invoke();
```

Or, if the method takes arguments (e.g. `int` and `String`)

```
int param1 = ...;
String param2 = ...;
klass.getMethod(a, new Class[] { Integer.class, String.class }).invoke(param1, param2);
```

Of course, you'll need to be catching appropriate exceptions.