# java generics return type of method should be same pass parameter passed

Tags: java

I want to return the object of class (which is passed as parameter to method) from the list. Also while return I need to cast the object to class I passed as parameter. My question is I tried to do as given below but its not correct since it is giving me compiler error "classToFind cannot be resolved to a type"

```
private <T extends myClass> T findObject(List<JAXBElement<? extends myClass>> list, 
          Class<? extends myClass> classToFind) {
    for (JAXBElement<? extends myClass> current : list) {
        if(current.getClass() == classToFind) {
               return (classToFind) currentClass; // error "classToFind cannot be resolved to a type"
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I want to return the "current" object  which matches the given class

Comment: Also "classToFind" is a reference to a Class object, but is itself not a type - so you cannot use it in the usual cast syntax. You would need to do something like classToFind.cast(currentClass). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321521/casting-a-class-using-reflection-in-java)

Comment: I just noticed: `current` will always be of type `JAXBElement`. If you want to check the type parameter at runtime you might have to use reflections. If it's possible at all. Have to pass on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say `return classToFind.cast(current)`. Unlike other solutions this is type-safe and does not need a `SuppressWarnings`. But, obviously, the second parameter has to be changed to `Class<T> classToFind` in any case.

Comment: Error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#16-of ? extends myClass to T

Comment: You might have overlooked the second sentence as I added it a bit later. Ofcourse the parameter must be parametrized with the same type variable as the return type to define the relationship.

Comment: But it does not make sure classToFind is derived from myClass

Comment: It *does*. `<T extends myClass>` already declares this. So `Class<T>` must represent myClass or a subclass of it.

Answer (score 1):

Without endorsing what you are doing this will work:

```
private JAXBElement<? extends myClass> findObject(List<JAXBElement<? extends myClass>> list, Class classToFind) {
for (JAXBElement<? extends myClass> current : list) {
        if (current.getClass() == classToFind) {
            return current;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
// This returns the actual value encapsulated inthe JAXBElement
private myClass findObject2(List<JAXBElement<? extends myClass>> list, Class classToFind) {
    for (JAXBElement<? extends myClass> current : list) {
        if (current.getClass() == classToFind) {
            return current.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile: change `class` to `Class` in the method signature

Comment: But it does not make sure classToFind is derived from myClass

Comment: Fixed the class issue. Introduced a second method findObject2 that returns the actual element embedded in the JAXBElement.  Also, Shivam, I agree that the first method's signature didn't guarantee it but the code would prove it in tests.  The 2nd method addresses your concern.